# Can I use em dashes around "namely, [...]"

Tags: em-dashes

For example:
While it did cause certain severe reactions in the audience **- namely, anger -** emotions are not the true purpose of...

Terrible example off the top of my head but I hope this exemplifies well enough what I am trying to ask.

The reason why I want to use em dashes is because I feel like there would just be too many commas if I used commas instead: While it did cause certain severe reactions in the audience **, namely, anger,** emotions are not the true purpose of...

^ (Especially if I were to use more commas near the end of the sentence).

Comment: Yes, you're ripe for a pair of em dashes—namely, these—to set off your remark.

Comment: Why would you think em dashes would be invalid? Please include any research you've done.